# Android: Built in drawables in different sizes?

Tags: android, size, drawable, scale

I'm using some of android's built in drawables, and am wondering whether they are available as vector graphics or in different sizes?  I'm making my layout for xlarge screens, and the drawables I'm using look a little small.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're available as PNG files in different sizes. Check [your-sdk-dir]/platforms/android-X/data/res and you'll see all of its drawable resources.

Comment: Thanks very much Flavio Faria!  Exactly what I was looking for.